# 3D secure sage pay payment integration in cs cart using php

Tags: php, opayo, cs-cart

sage pay payment integration using cs cart is running fine on one of my customer's shopping website.

Recently my customer upgraded his account and activated 3d secure with sage pay. Do I need to update any thing in cs cart? or it will automatically work on sage pay server after successful verification of card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which integration method you are using. Both Server and Form integration methods will work fine, whereas the Direct authentication method will require you to manually redirect the user to the 3D secure provider if required.

Comment: I'm not sure, I've only ever used the Server and Form integration kits, what payment method are you using?